# Is there a way to plot the confidence intervals of the logistic regression coefficients on python?

Tags: python, logistic-regression, statsmodels

After spending some time searching for information, I found out that I can execute the following Python code to perform logistic regression analysis:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm

# fit logistic regression model
model = sm.Logit(y, X).fit()

# extract logistic regression line slopes
coefficients = model.params

# get the confidence intervals of the slops
confint = model.conf_int()
```

I would like to draw a confidence interval of the regression coefficients based on the output `confint`. What are the ways of doing this? (note: I don't have to stick to the `statsmodels` module. I can use other modules to conduct a logistic regression analysis and to plot the confidence intervals of the regression slopes)

Thank you,